# Can i send Midi system exclusive from Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, web, system, midi

I do need to use chrome to trigger and send midi exclusive midi message and send it to a synthesizer hardware can chrome do it ? any framework ? any tutorial link that could get me on track , thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are requesting access to the MIDI device, you need to set `sysex` in the [options](https://webaudio.github.io/web-midi-api/#MIDIOptions) (see the [examples](https://webaudio.github.io/web-midi-api/#examples)).

You can the use [`MIDIoutput`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-midi-api/#MIDIOutput)`.send()` like with any other message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i was looking for a link that have more details or an example to send sysex, thanks.